# Can't properly configure Autoprefixer in npm scripts

Tags: npm, npm-scripts, postcss, autoprefixer

I'm trying to configure PostCSS Autoprefixer but it doesn't work. It should output new `style.prefix.css` file in the same 'css' folder. Please help me to understand, what is wrong with my npm script/setup

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "sb-demo-website",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "demo website",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "sass": "node-sass-chokidar sass/main.scss css/style.css -w --recursive --skip-initial",
    "compile-sass": "node-sass-chokidar sass/main.scss css/style.comp.css",
    "prefix-css": "postcss css/style.comp.css -o css/style.prefix.css --use autoprefixer"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "author": "tk",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": ""
  },
  "homepage": "",
  "browserslist": "last 3 versions",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "node-sass-chokidar": "^1.5.0",
    "postcss": "^8.0.5",
    "postcss-cli": "^7.1.2"
  }
}
```

and here is output when I run my script:

```
$ npm run prefix-css

> sb-demo-website@1.0.0 prefix-css C:\Users\tk\Documents\Study\web\css\demo1
> postcss css/style.comp.css -o css/style.prefix.css --use autoprefixer

Error: PostCSS plugin autoprefixer requires PostCSS 8. Update PostCSS or downgrade this plugin.
    at Processor.normalize (C:\Users\tk\Documents\Study\web\css\demo1\node_modules\postcss-cli\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:167:15)
    at new Processor (C:\Users\tk\Documents\Study\web\css\demo1\node_modules\postcss-cli\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:56:25)
    at postcss (C:\Users\tk\Documents\Study\web\css\demo1\node_modules\postcss-cli\node_modules\postcss\lib\postcss.js:55:10)
    at C:\Users\tk\Documents\Study\web\css\demo1\node_modules\postcss-cli\index.js:216:14
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sb-demo-website@1.0.0 prefix-css: `postcss css/style.comp.css -o css/style.prefix.css --use autoprefixer`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sb-demo-website@1.0.0 prefix-css script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\tk\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-09-18T17_50_55_597Z-debug.log
```

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like latest Autoprefixer v10.0.0 is kinda [broken](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer/issues/1359) right now. Downgrading it to version 9.8.6 resolved mentioned above issue.

I'm posting this as an answer in case someone else experience similar errors.